# dropdown search does no element found

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 screen one for details and another one for updating, when click on edit icon in the navbar the user will navigate to the edit screen containing the form, I have a field which is a `DropdownSearch` containing the name of my customer. so the problem is when click on the edit button i got an exception saying ***"StateError (Bad state: No element)"*** but when i click on continue in VS-Code the exception disappear and the dropdown search element are found.

I've tried to set the value to *null* if no element was found but i got an error because `<String, dynamic>` can't be *null* and I've tried to change the code in different ways but it did not work.

Find my code below:

```
import 'package:dropdown_search/dropdown_search.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:invoice_app/Controller/db_helper.dart';
import 'package:invoice_app/Controller/language_constants.dart';
import 'package:invoice_app/Model/Invoice/invoice.dart';
import 'package:invoice_app/Views/Invoice/UserData.dart';
import 'package:invoice_app/Views/Invoice/UserDataNotifier.dart';
import 'package:invoice_app/Views/Invoice/invoiceForm.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'add_item.dart';
import 'generate_pdf.dart';

class edit extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> invoiceData;

  const edit({required this.invoiceData});

  @override
  _editState createState() => _editState();
}

class _editState extends State<edit> {
  final invoiceForm inv = new invoiceForm();
  int _currentPageIndex = 0;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _customerIdsAndNames = [];

  final _iInvoiceDateController = TextEditingController();
  final _iUsernameController = TextEditingController();
  final _totalAmountNoVatController = TextEditingController();
  final _totalAmountWithVatController = TextEditingController();
  final _iServerId1Controller = TextEditingController();
  final _iServerId2Controller = TextEditingController();
  final _currencyTypeController = TextEditingController();
  final _totalDiscountNoVatController = TextEditingController();
  final _totalGrossAmountNoVatController = TextEditingController();
  final _vatRateController = TextEditingController();
  String _statusMessage = '';

  final List<String> invoiceTypes = [
    'waybill invoice',
    'bill of sale',
    'order invoice',
  ];
  String _discountType = 'percentage';

  final List<String> invoiceStatuses = [
    'issued',
    'paid',
  ];
  final List<String> currencyType = [
    'USD',
    'TL',
    'GBP',
  ];
  String? _selectedInvoiceType;
  String? _selectedInvoiceStatus;
  String? _selectedCustomerId;
  String? _selectedCurrency;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedCustomerId = widget.invoiceData['i_customer_id'];
  }

  void _fetchCustomers() async {
    try {
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> customerIdsAndNames =
          await fetchCustomerIdsAndNamesFromDatabase();
      setState(() {
        _customerIdsAndNames = customerIdsAndNames;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error fetching customer IDs and names: $error');
    }
  }

  void _updateInvoice(Map<String, dynamic> invoiceData) async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      // Create the Invoices object with updated data
      final updatedInvoice = Invoices(
        iInvoiceId: widget.invoiceData['i_invoice_id'],
        iCustomerId: _selectedCustomerId,
        iInvoiceDate: DateTime.parse(_iInvoiceDateController.text),
        iUsername: _iUsernameController.text,
        iInvoiceType: _selectedInvoiceType,
        iInvoiceStatus: _selectedInvoiceStatus,
        iCurrencyType: _selectedCurrency,
        iTotalGrossAmountNoVat:
            double.parse(_totalGrossAmountNoVatController.text),
        iTotalDiscountNoVat: double.parse(_totalDiscountNoVatController.text),
        iTotalAmountNoVat: double.parse(_totalAmountNoVatController.text),
        iTotalAmountWithVat: double.parse(_totalAmountWithVatController.text),
        iServerId1: _iServerId1Controller.text == "null" ||
                _iServerId1Controller.text.isEmpty
            ? 0
            : int.parse(_iServerId1Controller.text),
        iServerId2: _iServerId2Controller.text == "null" ||
                _iServerId2Controller.text.isEmpty
            ? 0
            : int.parse(_iServerId2Controller.text),
        iCreateDate: DateTime.parse(
          widget.invoiceData?['i_create_date'] ?? DateTime.now().toString(),
        ),
        iLastTargetUpdate: DateTime.now(),
        iLastSourceUpdate: DateTime.now(),
        s_code: widget.invoiceData['s_code'],
      );

      // Perform the update operation
      final rowsAffected = await updateInvoice(updatedInvoice);
      Navigator.pop(context, widget.invoiceData);

      // Show a success message after successful update
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Invoice updated successfully!')),
      );

      // Navigate back to the invoice detail page
      Navigator.pop(context, rowsAffected > 0);
    }
  }



  Future<int> updateInvoice(Invoices invoices) async {
    final db = await customerDataBase();
    return await db.update(
      "invoices",
      invoices.toMap(),
      where: 's_code = ?',
      whereArgs: [invoices.s_code],
    );
  }

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        // Clear the userDataNotifier when navigating back using the app bar arrow
        context.read<UserDataNotifier>().setUserData(UserData());
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Edit  ${widget.invoiceData["i_invoice_id"]}"),
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _updateInvoice(widget.invoiceData);
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.grey[800],
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Card(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Positioned.fill(
                        child: IndexedStack(
                          index: _currentPageIndex,
                          children: [
                            _buildInvoiceForm(),
                            AddItemPage(),
                            GeneratePdfPage(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ))),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          currentIndex: _currentPageIndex,
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _currentPageIndex = index;
            });
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.description),
              label: translation(context).invoice,
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
              label: translation(context).addItem,
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.picture_as_pdf),
              label: translation(context).generatePdf,
            ),
          ],
          selectedItemColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildInvoiceForm() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
                child: DropdownSearch<Map<String, dynamic>>(
              items: _customerIdsAndNames,
              onChanged: (Map<String, dynamic>? selectedValue) {
                if (selectedValue != null) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedCustomerId = selectedValue['c_code'];
                  });
                }
              },
              itemAsString: (Map<String, dynamic>? item) {
                return item?['c_name'];
              },
              selectedItem: _selectedCustomerId != null
                  ? _customerIdsAndNames.firstWhere(
                      (item) => item['c_code'] == _selectedCustomerId)
                  : null,
              popupProps: PopupPropsMultiSelection.menu(
                showSearchBox: true,
                fit: FlexFit.loose,
                searchFieldProps: TextFieldProps(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: translation(context).customers,
                    labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps(
                dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: translation(context).customers,
                  labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                ),
                baseStyle: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return translation(context).customerIsRequired;
                }
                return null;
              },
            )),
      
            Text(
              _statusMessage,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```